# How to add GNOME Shell dash folders to the launcher dock

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

It is possible to group applications in GNOME Shell dash into folders. But I couldn't figure out how to add these dash folders to the GNOME Shell dock (launcher). I wonder if there is a way to do this.